# Problema com a soma de 10 números com for

Tags: delphi, for, pascal

Estou com uma dúvida em um algoritmo que soma 10 números com o comando de repetição `for`.

```
soma_numero := soma_numero + idade;
```

Quando declaro a `soma_numero` como 0 antes do `for` o algoritmo roda normalmente, mas seu eu não declarar como 0 ele imprime um valor não esperado.

```
begin
  soma_idade := 0;
  for cont := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      writeln('Digite a idade ', cont);
      readln(idade);
      soma_idade := soma_idade + idade;
    end;
  writeln('A soma das idades e ', soma_idade);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: E cadê o código do seu `for`?

Comment: Já adicionei o código

Comment: Não consegui simular o problema. Para mim, o seu código sempre funciona normalmente mesmo sem a inicialização do `soma_idade`. Veja aqui o teste: https://ideone.com/i9UR6O

Comment: @VictorStafusa o Delphi é muito fraco com gerenciamento de memória, sem inicializar a variável ela pode receber "lixo" de memória. *Aguardando ser reaberta para posta uma resposta*.

Comment: Entendi o problema, que era o "lixo" já armazenado na variável, obrigado.

Comment: Por padrão a variável já deveria iniciar com valor zero mas para evitar problemas e facilitar o entendimento do código é melhor inicializa-la com o valor correto antes de utilizar. Isso pode evitar muita dor de cabeça depois

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, ia responder essa pergunta, mas como vi que você estava aguardando a mesma ser reaberta resolvi te avisar para responder.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos tudo bem amigo, pode responder. Mas é isto que comentei mesmo, nós mesmo temos que controlar a gestão da memória!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> resposta dada nos comentários e aceita como correta:

O Delphi é muito fraco com gerenciamento de memória, sem inicializar a variável ela pode receber "lixo" de memória.